# MATLAB: Looking for faster/more elegant way to compute a moving median absolute deviation for very long time series

Tags: matlab, performance, median, large-data

I have a very large array with five channels and approximately 6 million entries (5 x 6000000). My goal is to sweep through the array with a 7-point window and remove "spikes" which are defined as being some scaled amount greater than the median absolute deviation (MAD).

I am testing the code by running only 10000 initial points of the time series. Currently, it takes about 3 seconds for me to run the first 10,000 points. I am running on a relatively old, 32-bit Dell laptop with 2.30 GHz processor and 4 GB of RAM. Obviously, if I was using a newer computer, I could complete the task very quickly. For example, my more powerful desktop completes the same task in 0.7 seconds. However, I need to run the code on a laptop, and cannot afford to wait 35 - 40 minutes every time I need to run the code.  I am looking for help finding inefficiencies and places where I can make the code faster.

Below is the code. Any suggestions for how to improve the speed is appreciated. I've noticed that the calculation for the "MAD" is the most time consuming (requiring about 1.9 seconds, or over half of the total time).

```
load('data.mat') % data (approx 5 channels x 6000000 data points (int32))
nscans = length(data); %number of data points in each channel

nwide = 7; %number of data points in the window

% Rejection parameters (not so important for the question)
iscale = 50; %scale factor for MAD
minmad = 2;
mincrit = [100 100 100 500 500];

nfixed=zeros(1,5);
L = floor(nwide/2); %half of window (odd window length only)

%Padding for beginning and end of data
data = [repmat(data(:,1),[1 L]) data repmat(data(:,end),[1 L])];

nfixed = zeros(1,5); %initialize counter
tic 
for n = L+1:10000
    idata = data(:,n-L:n+L)'; % temporary window

    % compute median of window
    med=median(idata);

    %compute median absolute deviation (MAD)
    % Note: mad = median(abs(X - median(X)))
    mad = median(abs(idata-repmat(median(idata),[nwide 1])));
    mad = max([mad;minmad*ones(1,5)]); %minmad threshold added

    %compute rejection threshold
    icrit=max([iscale*mad;mincrit]);

    for i = 1:5 %loop over channels
        if abs(data(i,n)-med(i)) > icrit(i) %if threshold is exceeded
            data(i,n)=med(i); %then replace with median value
            nfixed(i)=nfixed(i)+1; %count number of replacements
        end
    end

end
toc

data = data(:,L+1:end-L)'; %remove padding
```

I feel like there is likely a more elegant way of doing the "repmat" command.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: When you remove a spike, does that affect the computation in future windows? It appears so form your code. It that's the case, it's hard to avoid a loop

Comment: I have to think about this more but the first thing is that you can do `array-scalar` without having to repmat it. That would probably save you some time.

Answer (score 2):

> Any suggestions for how to improve the speed is appreciated.

You can tighten up your code a bit by not repeating your `median(idata)` call a second time.

Change this:

`mad = median(abs(idata-repmat(median(idata),[nwide 1])));`

to this:

`mad = median(abs(idata-repmat(med,[nwide 1])));`

Alternatively, you may get more mileage out of [MATLAB's mad](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mad.html) function, it came about before 2006.  You'll need to change your variable names though.

For example, you could change your code from this:

```
mad = median(abs(idata-repmat(median(idata),[nwide 1])));
mad = max([mad;minmad*ones(1,5)]); %minmad threshold added
```

to

```
madV = max(mad(idata);[2 2 2 2 2]);
```

I just placed the vector of 2's in there as nothing in the code shows `minmad` being updated.

Comment: It's unlikely that matlab's `mad` command would help. I looked at the source code and it's exactly his implementation with more overhead. Likely it would take longer unless versions prior to 2017b had it mexed and they changed it back for whatever reason.

Comment: @Durkee I see what you mean about `mad()`.  Hopefully calling `median(idata)` once instead of twice will still help some.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `movmedian` to get the moving median?

```
med = movmedian(data,7,2,'Endpoints','discard');
```

Try to avoid for-loops if at all possible.

For example:

```
data = randn([5,1E6]);tic;
med = movmedian(data,7,2); %moving median
dev = abs(data-med); %deviation from median
thres = median(dev,2); %threshold
rep = dev>thres; %points to replace
data(rep) = med(rep); %replace data with median
toc
>>Elapsed time is 0.285828 seconds.
memory
>>Memory used by MATLAB:      1629 MB (1.708e+09 bytes)
```